# Fixed Button Position Relative to ImageView in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

In my project I would like to essentially 'Pin' a button to a certain position on an image. The imageView scales to the screen size from the centre and maintains its aspect ratio.

I am trying to make it so that each button remains over the chakras "coloured icons in centre of body". I need them to maintain a scale that is the size of the chakras and maintain their position over the chakras regardless of screen size.

[Wanted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZDPO.png)

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hln.png)

[Scaling Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h0TK.png)

[Aspect Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWbSk.png)

Comment: If you have all the pins images you can simply used them as the buttons' background.

Comment: you can align the buttons on the horizontal centre, and fix the vertical position as a percentage of the height

Comment: try to fix your ajna chakra :)))

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example - you will want to play with the exact positioning, but this should show you the method.  You can do everything using auto layout in Xcode.

I took one of your images, and edited it to remove the buttons, and used it as the image in a `UIImageView` filling the screen of a `UIViewController`

Then I created 7 small buttons, and added constraints to them width & height = 20, and Align Centre Y to Image View

The tricky part is to add a constraint to align the centre of each button to a fixed percentage of the `UIImageView` centre - and that will be trial and error until it looks right.

Here's how to set the constraint

[image: Set vertical constraint]

here's the app running on the iPhone 12 simulator

[image: iPhone 12]

and here it is on an iPad (12.9 inch)

[image: iPad Portrait]

and here in landscape

[image: iPad landscape]

Answer (score 0):

You can take parent containerView for each imageView and Button.
Please see the picture to this link for better understand.

https://ibb.co/dsTjxbw